# Create multiple instances of firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple Firebase databases, and I would like to create one admin which connects to all databases. To initialize the app I first require the Firebase-admin module and initialize the app. If I run this again with different credentials it will still only initialize the one app.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
...


Object.keys(config).map(function (k, i){

var c = config[k];

var serviceAccount = require(c.credential);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    apiKey: c.apiKey,
    authDomain: c.authDomain,
    databaseURL: c.databaseURL,
    storageBucket: c.storageBucket
}, c.name);
...
}
```

This does not work! Only one app is initialized even though there are two configurations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
// Initialize the default app
firebase.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
var otherApp = firebase.initializeApp(otherAppConfig, "other");

console.log(defaultApp.name);  // "[DEFAULT]"
console.log(otherApp.name);    // "other"

// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
var defaultAuth = firebase.auth();
var defaultDatabase = firebase.database();

// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
var otherAuth = otherApp.auth();
var otherDatabase = otherApp.database();
```

Check out the [Initialize mutltiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_multiple_apps) docs of the Firebase Admin SDK setup guide for more details.

Comment: although its not the accepted answer, this worked for me

Comment: This, without a doubt, should be the accepted answer because it shows how to use the methods after initialization

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out...

```
var app = admin.initializeApp({... })

var db = admin.database(app);
```

Comment: The 'app' should also be added as a 2nd parameter:
var app = admin.initializeApp({... }, 'app');

Answer (score 2):

With firebase 9:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const mainServiceAccount = require('./path/to/main/serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(mainServiceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<MAIN_DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});

const secondaryAdmin = require('./path/to/secondary/serviceAccountKey.json');
const secondaryAppConfig = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(secondaryServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://<SECONDARY_DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
};
const secondary = initializeApp(secondaryAdmin, 'secondary');

const ref1 = admin.database().ref(path);

const ref2 = secondary.database().ref(path2);
```

Comment: this solution worked for me. But it's better to pass firebase creds as env variables.

Comment: Totally agree. It is good practice to use environment variables.